# How do I remove the gradient from UIToolbar in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitoolbar

I am using `UIToolbar` in iPad App,How can I remove the gradient background from it? Below is my Code.

```
aToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
aToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; toolbar.alpha = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set image  in UIToolbar so remove Gradient.

My suggestion is please set image and create custom UItoolbar.

For that code is below.

```
   UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] 
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    // Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```